# Why can't I specify my rootfs with PARTUUID when I use initramfs?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, initrd

I have an embedded ARM board and am experimenting with initramfs.

Since my root filesystem is EXT4 and the *EXT4 driver is built into the kernel* (not compiled as a module), I can directly boot the kernel and mount the root filesystem, no initramfs required. **Without initramfs**, the kernel won't recognize filesystem UUIDs, of course, hence **I specified root with the partition identifier PARTUUID**, as described in the kernel docs. The boot argument in question looks like this:
root=PARTUUID=7acc80f1-01
**This works perfectly fine.**

Now, when I try to boot the same kernel version **with an initramfs, the system won't boot**. It complains the root device cannot be found. When I change my boot arguments to **use the filesystem UUID intstead of the PARTUUID, then it works again**:
root=UUID=c9fd552c-921c-4ddb-bb46-fe557943d311
But why is that? *Why would using an initramfs lead to less boot options when the kernel supports PARTUUID natively in the first place?*

I'd like to specify root in unique way that works in both setups, regardless of whether an initramfs is used or not. Device names such as /dev/sda1 are not an option as they can vary during boot (multiple disks attached).

Any clues?

Thanks and regards,

Timo

P.S: The kernel version is mainline 4.4.16. U-Boot is 2015.5. Distro is Debian 8.

Comment: Small typo: U-Boot version is 2016.5, not 2015.5.

Comment: You may [edit] your question for improving it (fix mistakes, append additional information, and so on).

Comment: `initramfs` has nothing to do with partitions. It's just an archive that is mounted as partition virtually in the kernel.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko: I don't really get what you're trying to say. initramfs provides early userspace to mount the root filesystem (useful for modular kernels when certain drivers are required to actually access the disk/filesystem). In that respect, it deals with devices/partitions/filesystems. But anyway, I figured out the issue myself. It's a known Debian issue, see my answer below.

Comment: initramfs is not a partition. That's my point.

Comment: Ok. Seems like a misunderstanding then. The issue was about mounting the *root* partition/filesystem - either directly or via an initramfs. But I never meant to imply that initramfs is a partition or that I wanted to mount the initramfs archive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out now. It's a known issue in Debian's initramfs-tools package: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=801154

The script used to mount the root filesystem by the initramfs doesn't support PARTUUID but only UUID. *This has been resolved in the testing distribution, but not in current stable (Jessie).*